# search entire Excel workbook for text string and highlight cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to search an entire Excel `workbook` containing multiple sheets for
text strings that may be present in multiple columns 
(say in the range column A to column J)

When a text string is found, it applies a color format to the cell.

Is this possible, or will I have to make a rule for each sheet?

An example:

- Find string "information" anywhere in my `workbook` and format cell blue

I have multiple different text strings to enter and each will have a different color format.
Is there a way to combine them all in one rule, or will this just need to have me create a new rule for each, using the same rule modified for each text string?

I'm really new at the conditional formatting in Excel, so if you could be gentle and walk me through each step that would be appreciated.

I have searched the oracle internet and found this solution.  I need to test it but it may do what I need.

This requires me to build a table called ChooseColors. The first column is the search string, the second is the colors -- pick from the available range. 
The search area is on a second sheet -- start on this sheet.

Code:

```
Sub DoColors()
Dim Picker As Variant
Dim Colors As Variant
Dim Rws As Long, j As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim Sht As String
Dim c As Range
Dim FirstAddress

Sht = ActiveSheet.Name
'load search strings and colors into arrays
Application.Goto Reference:="ChooseColors"
ReDim Picker(1 To Selection.Rows.Count)
ReDim Colors(1 To Selection.Rows.Count)
For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
Picker(i) = ActiveCell.Value
Colors(i) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i
'search the test range, changing backgrounds as required
Sheets(Sht).Activate
For i = 1 To UBound(Picker)
With Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    Set c = .Find(Picker(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = Colors(i)
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: new condition with new color has to be a new rule

Comment: You tag your questions with [excel-vba] as well, so you are open to code a vba solution?

Comment: You're definitely going to need a macro for this.  VBA to the rescue here! :D

Comment: I dont mind if its VBA as there are already some other VBA solutions in the sheet and macros enabled already

Comment: Edit your OP and post you code there - it's very difficult to read it in a comment...

Comment: I've edited your question - when you say `workset` with multiple sheets I take it you mean `Workbook`?  `Workset` looks like a misspelling of `Worksheet` which is just a single sheet within the file (`Workbook`).

Comment: er sure, sorry habits from other programs sneaking in there.  (Worksets from an Autodesk application)  - Thanks for fixing up the errors that is what I meant for it say using the correct techical terms for excel.

Comment: script added to OP.  However this will return only 1 string, and only 1 possible highlight color.  Is there any way to include the other strings in the same module or do I simply create multiple modules?

Comment: That code will almost work for whichever sheet is currently active and providing the searched text is on the sheet - if it isn't you'll get an _Object variable or With block variable not set_ error.  You need to remove the brackets from around the `w` and check the `FIND` doesn't return `Nothing`... then you need to get it to look at each sheet in turn without activating or selecting any cells (that just slows it down).

Comment: You changed your code... my previous comment might not be relevant any  more.

Answer (score 0):

This code, based on the first set of code you posted, will highlight all occurrences of whatever text you type in within the workbook.

```
Public Sub find_highlight()

    'Put Option Explicit at the top of the module and
    'Declare your variables.
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String

    FindString = InputBox("Information")

    'Use For...Each to cycle through the Worksheets collection.
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Find the first instance on the sheet.
        Set FoundCell = wrkSht.Cells.Find( _
            What:=FindString, _
            After:=wrkSht.Range("A1"), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)
        'Check it found something.
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            'Save the first address as FIND loops around to the start
            'when it can't find any more.
            FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
            Do
                With FoundCell.Interior
                    .ColorIndex = 6
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                End With
                'Look for the next instance on the same sheet.
                Set FoundCell = wrkSht.Cells.FindNext(FoundCell)
            Loop While FoundCell.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If

    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

---

To find more than one value and format you could use the following code.
It relies on a sheet I've called `Info` which has the values to look for in the range A1:A3.
The background to these values have been coloured as you want and the code just finds the matching values and copies the colour over.
[image]

You could add extra code to allow for more values, or use a dynamic named range to return your source values.
A dynamic named range would consist of a formula such as:  `=Info!$A$1:INDEX(Info!$A:$A,COUNTA(Info!$A:$A))` with a given name of 'SourceValues'.
Select `Define Name` on the `Formula` ribbon and paste the formula into the `Refers To:` box and the `SourceValues` into the name.
[image]
You'd then refer to the range with `Set Information = Range("SourceValues")`

```
Public Sub find_highlight()

    'Put Option Explicit at the top of the module and
    'Declare your variables.
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim InfoBit As Range
    Dim Information As Range

    Set Information = Range("SourceValues")
    'Set Information = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("A1:A3")

    'Use For...Each to cycle through the information we're looking for.
    For Each InfoBit In Information
        'Use For...Each to cycle through the Worksheets collection.
        For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            'Ignore the "Info" sheet as it holds our values to search for.
            If wrkSht.Name <> "Info" Then
                'Find the first instance on the sheet.
                Set FoundCell = wrkSht.Cells.Find( _
                    What:=InfoBit, _
                    After:=wrkSht.Range("A1"), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
                'Check it found something.
                If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                    'Save the first address as FIND loops around to the start
                    'when it can't find any more.
                    FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
                    Do
                        'Copy all formatting - bit of screen flicker.
'                        InfoBit.Copy
'                        FoundCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

                        'Just copy the Interior colour.
                        FoundCell.Interior.Color = InfoBit.Interior.Color

                        'Look for the next instance on the same sheet.
                        Set FoundCell = wrkSht.Cells.FindNext(FoundCell)
                    Loop While FoundCell.Address <> FirstAddress
                End If
            End If
        Next wrkSht
    Next InfoBit

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  The first example I gave only found 1 particular string but I need the code to search for multiple strings and apply multiple different colors.  The one I posted above has "half" worked.  I am getting an error on this line and not sure why - Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress

Comment: I've added code to find multiple strings.  Just need to add a new sheet containing those multiple strings.

Comment: Thanks Darren, you lost me a bit on how to modify this to include multiple strings.

Comment: To add a named range:- On the `Formulas` ribbon select `Name Manager`.  Click `New` and add the formula I gave into the `Refers to:` box, remembering to update sheet names in the formula (they've got to be in there or the formula will refer to the activesheet).  Give it a name (SourceValues) and then change this line:  `Set Information = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("A1:A3")` to `Set Information = Range("SourceValues")` and the code should be good to go.

Comment: Ok I've tried this out but I'm completely lost, I'm putting it down to end of work day brain meltdown.  I will be back on wednesday and trying to get this to work.  I can't work out where you want me to put this formula, and why it's not working.  Also I am getting an error on the line you told me to replace.

Comment: You're getting the error because the named range isn't set up, so the code can't find it. I've added updated the post to show where the formula goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Darren, the images definately help actually.  I'll be back attacking this today, so hopefully I can get it to work as you describe.  I also Wonder if I have some issue with my version of excel as a work colleague is getting different results to me using the same code and procedure.  Anyhow, I will see if I can get this to work first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for a good VBA solution when it is needed... but here you are better off using **Find + Replace** (Ctrl + H / Cmd + H). Click the "Options" button and next to the replace you can format the text to replace it with. Select "Format" then fill then the blue color. Put "information" in both the find and replace fields and run :)

Comment: Thanks, yes that works for one string, but I have multiple strings and multiple different colors to apply to.  Having said that, time its taken me to find a VBA code I can adapt I probably could have done the find and replace.