# Find string, change color across all Excel Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, string, colors

[search entire Excel workbook for text string and highlight cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547221) appears to be exactly what I need but I can't get it to work on my Excel workbook.  I have hundreds of rows across 10 worksheets.  All searched-for *Strings* (Packet 01, Packet 02, Packet 03, etc) would be in `B:8` to row-end on `worksheet(1)` and `B:7` to row-end on the other  9 worksheets (Worksheets are named and the `InputBox` result for the string would need to be case-sensitive). 45547221 indicates interior color change, but there would be too much color with all strings having cells in different colors, thus changing the string color would be better using `font.color.index`.  Trying the 45547221 code as-is finds it skipping the `Do/Loop While` code when in step mode.

I would modify the code in 45547221 by adding at a minimum:

```
Dim myColor As Integer
myColor = InputBox("Enter Color Number (1-56)")
```

(Configured so I can enter up to 5 FindStrings and 5 ColorIndex numbers as `Dim` with InputBox(es)) 
     In the `Do/Loop While` I would change `.ColorIndex = myColor`

I would like to get this code working as it seems to fit my needs - modified to find string instances across workbook and re-color string instead of cell interior colors and (2) get it to recognize the `Do/Loop While` code which it isn't now but would apply the `ColorIndex` number to each string.

---

```
Public Sub find_highlight()

    'Put Option Explicit at the top of the module and
    'Declare your variables.
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MyColor As Integer 'Added this

    FindString = InputBox("Enter Search Word or Phrase")
    MyColor = InputBox("Enter Color Number")

    'Use For...Each to cycle through the Worksheets collection.
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Find the first instance on the sheet.
        Set FoundCell = wrkSht.Cells.Find( _
            What:=FindString, _
            After:=wrkSht.Range("B1"), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)
        'Check it found something.
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            'Save the first address as FIND loops around to the start
            'when it can't find any more.
            FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
            Do
                With FoundCell.Font 'Changed this from Interior to Font
                    .ColorIndex = MyColor
                    '.Pattern = xlSolid
                    '.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic 'Deactivated this
                End With
                'Look for the next instance on the same sheet.
                Set FoundCell = wrkSht.Cells.FindNext(FoundCell)
            Loop While FoundCell.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If

    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Comment: Include the code in your question *as you tried to modify it* and explain exactly how it didn't work (or what error you got if that's the problem).  Since the linked code seems to be functional, it's impossible to guess exactly why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: First... Trying to set off code here with <Ctrl-K> but failed.  I built a stand-alone file with 5 worksheets.  Modified to add Dim MyColor As Integer, and MyColor = InputBox("Color") and .ColorIndex = [Number] to .ColorIndex = MyColor, then changed With FoundCell.Interior to With FoundCell.Font and deleted .Pattern = xlSolid and .PatternColorIndex = Automatic.  The original and modified code worked on the stand-alone.  I put it in the workbook I need it it as a ThisWorkbook module and on step-through highlighted If Not FoundCell Is Nothing and it jumped past the Do code.

Comment: If you add your complete code to the question someone will format it for you.

Comment: Tim,  Thank you.  Thought that the Stackhouse reference was enough.  Edited the post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This worked for me on your sample data, using a partial match so you can enter (eg) "Packet 03" and still match.

I like to split out the "find all" function into a separate function: it makes the rest of the logic easier to follow.

```
Public Sub FindAndHighlight()

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim FoundCells As Range, FoundCell As Range
    Dim MyColor As Integer 'Added this
    Dim rngSearch As Range, i As Long, rw As Long

    FindString = InputBox("Enter Search Word or Phrase")
    MyColor = InputBox("Enter Color Number")

    'Cycle through the Worksheets
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

        Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)

        rw = IIf(i = 1, 8, 7) '<<< Row to search on
                              '    row 8 for sheet 1, then 7

        'set the range to search
        Set rngSearch = wrkSht.Range(wrkSht.Cells(rw, "B"), _
                        wrkSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

        Set FoundCells = FindAll(rngSearch, FindString) '<< find all matches

        If Not FoundCells Is Nothing Then
            'got at least one match, cycle though and color
            For Each FoundCell In FoundCells.Cells
                FoundCell.Font.ColorIndex = CInt(MyColor)
            Next FoundCell
        End If

    Next i

End Sub

'return a range containing all matching cells from rng
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    'partial match...
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True) 'case-sensitive
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        If rv Is Nothing Then
            Set rv = f
        Else
            Set rv = Application.Union(rv, f)
        End If
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: On stepping the code advances and highlights the 'Do Until f Is Nothing' and then skips to the 'Set FindAll  = rv' line without any processing.  I attempted this on a clean Excel where I have Packet 02 in 5 places on each worksheet with (only string in cell). No other modules.  I also tried on my big spreadsheet which has the searched-for string in a string, i.e., C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\STEPHANIE\Audios\Packet 02 - WAV\WAV File 02.wav.  There are other modules - your code in its on worksheet module.  I am baffled.  Check in whole cell and in mid-string.

Comment: Sheet1 has a listing of all files.  I have coded to find file extensions and copy the rows to the appropriate Sheet, e.g., Documents, Audios, etc.  That function works fine.  An alternative might be to find the string and highlight on Sheet1 as a SUB and then run the SUB which identifies the extension and copies the rows.  Would this help?

Comment: I can't follow what you're talking about.  Remember I don't know anything about what you're doing or what your workbook looks like.  All I have seen is the code you posted.

Comment: I have constructed a spreadsheet.  The goal is to have all FindStrings found and MyColor applied across all worksheets.  I have your code as a Worksheet Module.  The other code I have constructed functions on multiple computers, hence the frustration.  I do not see a way to upload the .xlsm or a .zip.  Is this possible?  Could I be missing something I need to click, invoke or check?

Comment: If you need to share a file you can upload to Dropbox/Box/Google etc and share the link here.

Comment: File resides in Dropbox with this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7h17d3wkbe3f09/HighlightTest.xlsm?dl=0  The goal/object would be to enter, e.g., "Packet 02" and have it color-changed across.  This was a new file, i.e., not other Modules to possibly interfere.

Comment: From your question I got the impression your data was in rows, but it looks like it's in columns, and are you looking for exact match (where you need to enter the full path to get a match), or partial (only part of the path) ?

Comment: Me bad on row/column syntax explanation.  Yes, the search would be down a column, row-by-row.  The only column to be searched is ColumnB (begining Row 8 to end on 1st worksheet and beginning Row 7 on other worksheets.  I would be looking for partial match within the path, i.e., only the words Packet 01, Packet 02, etc. Apologies . . . how this clarifies.

Comment: Tim ... just returned and ran the new code, but it highlights the entire string in which the term is found.  I am seeking to highlight just the search term.  The "problem" would be that if there are 10, 15 or more terms (e.g., Packet 02, Packet 03, Packet 04, etc.), the resulting sheets would be overly "busy" with color, hence the reason of just highlighting the term.  This solution is otherwise perfect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215498/find-and-highlight-a-specific-word-in-a-range-of-cells

Comment: Tim ... Thank you for the link to 20215498.  It took a while to figure it out by substituting/deleting/adding, but it seems to work and I intended.  A good learning experience.  Here is a link to the finished code.  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/811d59n4nn3jru50kwg2q/HighlightTest-DONE.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=gf28dvr0igyzny6lbrbuh6hq2